# .NET Com Interopability

Tags: .net, com, vb6

I have a C# class X which inherits from class Y. Class X should be Com-Visible (should be used in an old Vb6 application). It is neccessary to use some Types of class Y in the VB6 application. How can I make them also COM-visible (without changing class Y) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change class Y, then I'd create new COM-visible wrappers that expose the data and types from class Y.